# Flutter - How to check multiple conditions while fetching data from firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch a good amount of data from firebase. When i normally load all data using **single** where clause it takes approximate 1 minute to load. i want to add multiple where clause so that i can check at the time of fetching so that i can optimize the time by not fetching unwanted data. How can i check **multiple conditions** while fetching the data from firebase realtimedatabase

Here is my code:

```
 var query = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(str_gender)
        .child('Facial Parts/Nose').orderByChild("noselength").equalTo(str_length);
```

Here i can check only by nose length but i want to filter it out by nose length,nosetype,nose width

in other language we can say

```
noselength=value and nosewidth=value and nosewidth=value
```

if condition satisfies then only i need to fetch data

so how to add multiple where clause in my existing code??

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add multiple conditions in realtime database. One solution is to create an attribute that will contain all 3 fields:

```
length_width_type : 10_10_normal
```

And then do:

```
 var query = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(str_gender)
        .child('Facial Parts/Nose').orderByChild("length_width_type").equalTo(value);
```

---

Other solution is to use firestore since it supports multiple `where` clause:

```
void getData() async {
  var result = await Firestore.instance
      .collection("str_gender")
      .where("noseLength", isEqualTo: 10)
      .where("noseWidth", isEqualTo: 10)
      .getDocuments();
}
```